# Error:12541 No listener Error Oracle 11g .Net Connectivity

Tags: java, asp.net, oracle, oracle11g, odp.net

i have installed oracle Enterprise Edition and it is working fine Then i have to use this oracle db in my Asp.net app so i have found connection string and now app is working fine on my localhost but when i uses this app on some other pc within same network then it is giving this error so what more configurations required to Fix this error

## My Listener.org file

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: G:\app\DigiWebT\product\11.2.0\dbhome_3    \network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = G:\app\DigiWebT\product\11.2.0\dbhome_3)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:G:\app\DigiWebT\product\11.2.0\dbhome_3    \bin\oraclr11.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1522))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.92)(PORT = 1522))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1522))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = G:\app\DigiWebT
```

## My tnsnames.org  file

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: G:\app\DigiWebT\product\11.2.0\dbhome_3\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1522))
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.92)(PORT = 1522))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1522))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1522))
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.92)(PORT = 1522))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

Comment: Shouldn't the filename extension be `.ora` and not `.org`?

Comment: these are oracle 11g database config files and i am sure they have .ora extension